# Cordova IOS external application only works in debug mode

Tags: ios, cordova

I've setup a phonegap app and try to make it run on ios platform. I've made the iOS platform with Cordova add platform iOS and opened the project with XCode.

I want to call an external application in my app which has an existing URL scheme. I removed the csp rules in my meta tags and I've allowed the URL scheme in my config.xml.

The problem is that it works perfectly fine when I debug the app with XCode on my iPad device  but it doesn't when I generate the ipa with Product->archive and export it as a developer IPA and install it on my device.

I have also tested it with normal URLs like window.open("http://www.google.de"), again, this works when I debug it with XCode on my iPad device but not when generate the ipa and install it on my device.

Any ideas what am I missing?

**EDIT:**
For some undefined reasons my config.xml inside the generated ipa from XCode differs ALOT from the debugging one. XCode uses the config.xml from the staging folder while XCode debugging use the config.xml from the main folder. I fixed the problem by editing the staging config.xml.